# Change ListView divider length based on longest Text in List

Tags: android, android-listview

I've been looking at things on `Stackoverflow` and cannot find out how to do this.

**What I want is something like this:**

```
    xxxxxxxx
    --------
    xxxx
    --------
    xx
```

**Instead of the usual**

```
    xxxxxxxx
    ----------------------------------- (until end of screen)
    xxxx
    -----------------------------------
    xx
```

I wonder if there is an really easy way to do it.

I figure it involves changing the right margin but that's about as far as I got.

I am creating my `ListViews` at run-time by the way.

Comment: Do you mean that the listview width should be longer but the divider should be of the length of the longest text in the list?

Comment: I don't think I need to change the listview width? The divider should be the length of the longest text in the list though yes.

Comment: I don't know if it will work but one thing you can try is while setting the view as an item for the listview, you can get the width of the view and check if its more than the previous one to set it as the listview width. the divider will be the same length as the listview. You may need to call invalidate() though. you can also find create the views in advance and find the longest view beforehand to avoid the performance to get affected.

Comment: @John61590 looking for soemthing like this http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=dmwpow&s=5. You can make divider color to the one in background add a border to the textview at the bottom i am not sure of your  requirement

Comment: @John you can also add border at the top.  is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this with a custom drawable :

```
<ListView
  android:divider="@drawable/fancy_gradient"
  android:dividerHeight="@dimen/divider_height"...
```

Java way :

```
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
int[] colors = {0, 0xFF97CF4D, 0};
ListView inner = list.getRefreshableView();
inner.setDivider(new GradientDrawable(Orientation.RIGHT_LEFT, colors));
inner.setDividerHeight(1);
```

But it seems that divider width is not customizable...

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't directly change divider width programmatically, I suggest writing an adapter which takes your string list. Adapter will be consisting of one TextView and one ImageView(preferably).

In the adapter you can compare strings and get the longest one. Get estimated width for that longest string by;

```
String longestText = "longestword";
Paint paint = new Paint();
float widthValue = paint.measureText(longestText);
```

(that will give you the result in pixels) And after getting this value, you can simply put an imageview of (height=x , width=widthValue) under the textview.

Then remove the divider from your listview in xml by;

```
android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
```

and your view as you desire is ready to use.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work I think. It seems to work.
Here is how I did it.

```
     ListAdapter listAdapter = posList.getAdapter();
                //base case
                int longestWidth = listAdapter.getView(0, null, posList).getMeasuredWidth();
                for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                    View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, posList);
                    listItem.measure(0, 0);
                    //check if the items in the list are longer than base case
                    if (listItem.getMeasuredWidth() > longestWidth)
                    {
                        longestWidth = listItem.getMeasuredWidth();
                    }

                }
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = posList.getLayoutParams();
                //assign width of textview to longest item in the list
                params.width = longestWidth;
```

Comment: not really changing the divider length, but doing it pseudo by changing the listview width to the size of the longest (text)view in the list.